# How do I use OSM custom tags in Mapbox style

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, tableau-api, cartocss

Here's a brief description of what I'd like to do (and I'm very, very new to this but seem to have hit a wall):

Display a map of color-coded buildings based on a custom tag (miamioh_lds).

What I've tried: in Mapbox Studio Classic starting with the Emerald style (coordinates 84.7286, 39.5033)

```
#building [miamioh_lds="uitcp"] {
  polygon-fill: #f61313;
}
```

I would expect Hoyt Hall to be red, but it is not, even if I remove all other #building CartoCSS statements.

I would like the building filled, which is why I'm using tags and fill instead of using a data source, which seems to be focused at adding markers. I'm using Mapbox because my goal is to bring the map into Tableau (which I'll use to add a marker off dynamic data, which is why I need a fill, not a marker here).

Can I use custom tags in CartoCSS? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no difference between "custom tags" and "regular tags". In the end it all depends on your stylesheet and whether your database contains all tags or just a limited set of them.

Comment: As it turns out, mapbox only gets a subset of tags. I was able to upload to mapbox a different set of tile sets, which resolved my issue.